# WPS running in silent Mode - is possible?

Tags: c#, mode, silent, wps

We have a application WPS (C# EXE) deployed by distribution system and it cannot be executed by script.
It's possible start it in "SILENT MODE" without modify the app?
I don't found any solution in the usually way

Thanks

Comment: https://silentinstallhq.com/wps-office-silent-uninstall-powershell/

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/appuser-itpro/run-setup-in-silent-mode